# Load php file with jquery in single.php

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, templates, page-template

I implemented in my worpdress theme ios button switch and when someone click the button the script load a php file with the text: on or off

Here is the code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$('#1').iphoneSwitch("<?php echo get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, '_fbpost_status', true); ?>", 
 function() {
   $('#ajax').load('<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/includes/ajaxswitch/on.php');
  },
  function() {
   $('#ajax').load('<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/includes/ajaxswitch/off.php');
  },
  {
    switch_on_container_path: '<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/includes/ajaxswitch/iphone_switch_container_off.png'
  });
```

So on.php have only the "Activated" text and of.php "Stoped" text. The on and off files have not included the wordpress variables. How can I include them? To make a update in db. Or do you know any better method for doing the update?

Comment: Your question is not very clear but you should probably be using the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) if you need WordPress variable and functions in those files.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, so in my question I have the script from single.php file, so yesterday I found out that I can define javascript variables via wp functions and tried this function:
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_frontend_data');
function my_frontend_data()
{
  global $current_user;
  wp_localize_script('data', 'Data', array(
    'userMeta' => get_user_meta($current_user->ID, '_fbpost_status', true),
    'templateUrl' => get_template_directory_uri()
  ));
}

But I get error, Data is not defined in javascript.

Comment: [Edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/95819/edit) your question with that additional information please. Formatting in the comments in very minimal making code hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), which is exactly the right core function for your needs.
A short explanation on the usage can be found in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96375/20992) to the question "Pass PHP variable to javascript".