# Pass PHP variable to javascript

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, pages, jquery, templates

Is there any possibility to pass some PHP variables in javascript so I can use them later?

Only in `single.php`.
I heard about `wp_enqueue_scripts` but with that it is neccesary to declare a path to a JS file, but I don`t need one.

Comment: What do you meand by _later_, and where do you want to use the variables (with respect to where the PHP variables are)? You can of course echo/print JavaScript code via PHP, and thus insert PHP variable values. But this is not what you want, I guess...

Comment: I created a new db table with some response.id`s from facebook api. This is the table: action_id, user_id,post_id, fb_id where fb_id is response.id from a facebook action. Then in single.php I have a button where if I press I must delete the fb action with api: FB.api('/'+fb.response, 'delete'); where fb.response should be fb_id from table.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Best practice method

Have a look at [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), which is meant to do exactly that.

But it *does require previous usage of [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)*, hence you will need to move your JS to a separate file indeed.
It will be worth those few minutes of effort though, for sure.

```
function wpse_96370_scripts()
{
    if ( is_single() ) {

        wp_register_script(
           'your_script_handle',
           get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/your-script.js',
           array( /* dependencies*/ ),
           1.0,
           true
       );

       wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script-handle' );

       $script_params = array(
           /* examples */
           'post' => 99,
           'users' => array( 1, 20, 2049 )
       );

       wp_localize_script( 'your-script-handle', 'scriptParams', $script_params );

    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_96370_scripts' );
```

In the JS you will then be able to use the passed parameters like so:

```
var posts = scriptParams.post,
    secondUser = scriptParams.users[1]; /* index starts at 0 */

// iterate over users
for ( var i = 0; i < scriptParams.users.length; i++ ) {
    alert( scriptParams.users[i] );
}
```

### [Edit] Your situation

As per your comment

> I created a new db table with some `response.id`s from facebook api. This is the table: action_id, user_id,post_id, fb_id where fb_id is response.id from a facebook action. Then in single.php I have a button where if I press I must delete the fb action with api: `FB.api('/'+fb.response, 'delete');` where `fb.response` should be `fb_id` from table.

Put the following your theme's `/js/` folder, create it, if it doesn't exist.
Let's call the file `fb-response.js`:

```
jQuery( '#button_id' ).click( function() {
    FB.api( '/' + fbParams.id, 'delete' );
});
```

Then register, enqueue and localize as seen above. Assuming that you have the ID you'd like to pass in let's say `$fb_id`:

```
wp_register_script(
    'fb-response',
     get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fb-response.js',
     array( 'jquery' ),
     1.0,
     true
);

wp_enqueue_script( 'fb-response' );

wp_localize_script( 'fb-response', 'fbParams', array( 'id' => $fb_id ) );
```

N.B. Obviously, the above is assuming this is in a theme. If we're talking "plugin", alter locations accordingly.

Comment: I am a little begginer in this, so I try to implement this to my wordpress: http://papermashup.com/jquery-iphone-style-ajax-switch/. As you can see there is a js file and a few lines of js code to put in the usage file. Or I can put that few lines of code on another file?

Comment: So for any small javascript action I should create a file? If you are avaible can you add on skype: sebyku17 ?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do, where you want to do that, and so on. Generally: No, you don't have to use an external JS file. But if you choose to, you can put whatever you want inside **one single file**. There's no need for multiple files if you have multiple functions, if that's what you were asking. However, you already accepted this (IMHO quite complex and in your case slightly _overkill_ sort of) answer - without having fully understood, as I take it. No offense, @Johannes. ;)

Comment: Well, in the end it boils down to personal preference, I suppose. But one thing's for sure: The larger your codebase becomes, the harder it will be too read later on, and the more important is keeping it clean. I, for one, do not like having server and client side code in the same file - with exceptions, obviously. A simple one-line `onclick` *can* certainly be left inline, but you also forfeit the power of `wp_localize_script`.

Comment: This is my page: http://funny-videoro.com/the-dark-knight-rises-trailer-oficial/, after you press on the player and login, at the bottom of player is a button, when you press to off should delete the facebook post. I will try to make a js file for all functions. Hope will work.

Comment: None taken, @tf. So far it might be borderline overkill, but for one his code might grow and for another, the initial question spoke of "variables", in plural form. Your answer is just as valid though, so +1 from me.

Comment: Sorry for missunderstandings, I want to make the code clean, php to php file and js to js file as Johannes Pille said.

Comment: My theme have 2 files: custom-functions.php and theme_functions.php, in custom I have something like:
`function my_deregister_scripts() {
 wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery'...
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui'...
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-superfish' ...
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-slider' `

And in theme functions: `function mytheme_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_scripts');`
Where should I register my php variables?

Comment: Where, @Sebastian, is again up to you. The important part is hooking the enqueueing with the [`wp_enqueue_scripts` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) - I have updated the above generic example to include that as well.

Comment: I made the changes, is working but I`m sure the code is not optim, I think is a mess there, is against to this site rules if I ask someone in private to look at my code? Is not a big deal and if you want I pay.

Comment: You may certainly hire a professional, but the stackexchange network is not meant to be a freelance platform. And if it was, I personally wouldn't have time for client work anyway. Sorry. Also note that comments aren't meant for extended discussions - this length probably already resulted in a moderator flag - glad to have helped, congrats on having gotten your code to work.

Comment: wp_localize_script is a very underused and powerful function for passing PHP values to a Javascript file. It's surprising not many people actually know about this powerful feature in Wordpress.

Comment: I feel the same, @DigitalSea - it is one of the features I love WP for the most.

Comment: Thank you, the idea was to pass variables without using a js file. Something like pass_var(js_var_name, php_array) and that is all.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/ should be a preferred option nowadays

EDIT:
From the docs above:

```php
function mytheme_enqueue_typekit() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme-typekit', 'https://use.typekit.net/.js', array(), '1.0' );
   wp_add_inline_script( 'mytheme-typekit', 'try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_typekit' );
```

So that you first enqueue the script, and **then** pass the variables

Yet this code simply generates the following

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://use.typekit.net/.js?ver=1.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){} </script>
```

In my case, I simply expose the data I need directly writing the JavaScript code (in the template) and using a global JS variable with a specific name (haven't found a better way) (using Timber, pure PHP should be equivalent)

```html
<script>
    my_global_variable.data1 = {{ custom_timber_function()|json_encode }}
</script>
```

```php
$twig->addFunction(new Timber\Twig_Function('custom_timber_function', function () {
    return [
      'theme' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri(),
    ];
}));
```

Comment: I agree with your assessment, but answers should be self-sufficient and not only a link. Can you please add an example and an explanation?

Comment: completely right

Answer (score 1):

Having read your comment, I understand you'd like to do something like this:

```
// Do something to get the ID
$facebook_id = ...

// Create and print the button
echo '<input onclick="FB.api('/'+'.$facebook_id.', 'delete')" />';
```

Comment: No, this is the page where I am working: http://funny-videoro.com/the-dark-knight-rises-trailer-oficial/ . If you want you can login to the website. Then you will see a jquery ios style button. When I slide to off I must delete with fb api a post. The post id is in the db.

Comment: Well, that is basically what I wrote in my answer. Retrieve the id from the database and store it in a variable. Then directly print it into your one-line JavaScript function call. The `<input ... />` and its function was for demonstrating purposes only. As far as I understood you, there's everything said what you need. If not, please try to explain some more, but in your question, not in comments.

Comment: I dont want to use php and js code in same line, in wordpress are some automatically functions ...