# Set variable in javascript and using in my shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode, javascript

my script is

```
function($) {
   var google_map_address = $('#address').text();
$(function () {
$('#gmap').gmap3({
    marker: {
        address: google_map_address 
    },
    map: {
        options: {
            zoom: 14
        }
    }
}); });})(jQuery);
```

and my php code is

```
    init_shortcode();
    function init_shortcode() {
    $shortcodes = array(
    'gmap' => 'spyrowebs_gmap');
    foreach( $shortcodes as $tag => $func )
        add_shortcode( $tag, $func );
    }  
    function spyrowebs_gmap( $atts = array(), $content = '' ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'address' =>'',
      );
    $atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts );
    extract( $atts );
    $address=$address;
    return ' <div class="gmap" id="gmap"><div id="address" style="display:none">'.$address.'</div></div>';
}
```

but this does not work i want to  create a shortcode like

```
[gmap address="your address"]
```

now what is the problem when i assign a value to javascript variable 
like

```
var google_map_address = 'your address';
```

then its work while in the above its not working please any help.
when i put the above code in my theme its work but when i use it in my plugin its not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass PHP variable to javascript](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96370/pass-php-variable-to-javascript)

Comment: Please don't use the wordpress.org tag.

Comment: Is the lacking `(` at the start of the first piece of JavaScript code a typo?

Comment: what do you mean? engelen

Comment: The `function($) {`, shouldn't that be `(function($) {`?

Comment: then what its should be and when i use like var google_map_address="your address" then its work but in variable case its not work

Answer (score 1):

Hey Guys i got the solution.

just include my script in footer instead of header.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'spyrowebs_gmap_enqueue_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `html()` instead if `text()` function.

Try:

```
var google_map_address = $('#address').html();
```

Comment: Matt, you should not post multiple answers to a question. If you need to add/remove/modify anything, please do it in an [edit] to you original answer

Comment: I just forgot one more thing, if you find your answer to be inappropriate or totally wrong, delete it before posting a new answer

Comment: @PieterGoosen Cool, will do - Thanks for the heads up on that :-)