# Correct was to customise theme using get_theme_mod in scripts

Tags: theme-development, themes, wp-enqueue-script, theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

Am currently using `get_theme_mod` to offer theme customisations in CSS which works great. Would now like to offer theme customisations where it would alter JavaScript. Am currently achieving this through the use of `wp_print_footer_scripts` however it causes initial problems with many optimisation plugins. For instance Autoptimize requires the altering of an advanced option to

> Also aggregate inline JS

which would suggest something's wrong and there has to be a way to achieve the same result but by using script enqueuing in a manner which is compatible with optimisation plugins.

Here are the two relevant excerpts of the code:

**Function for adding inline JavaScript**

```
function theme_customize_js() {
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function($){
        'use strict';

        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
          animateIn: '<?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_animatein', 'fadeIn' ); ?>',
          animateOut: '<?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_animateout', 'fadeOut' ); ?>',
          autoHeight: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_autoplay', False ) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
          autoplay: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_autoplay', True ) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
          autoplaySpeed: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_autoplayspeed', 'false' ); ?>,
          center: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_center', True ) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
          dots: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_dots', True ) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
          dotsSpeed: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_dotsspeed', 'false' ); ?>,
          dragEndSpeed: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_dragendspeed', 'false' ); ?>,
          fluidSpeed: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_fluidspeed', False ) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
          items: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_items', 1 ); ?>,
          loop: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_loop', True ) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
          nav: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_nav', True ) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
          navSpeed: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_navspeed', 'false' ); ?>,
          navText : [
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>'
          ],
          smartSpeed: <?= get_theme_mod( 'carousel_smartspeed', 250 ); ?>
        });
      })(jQuery);
    </script>
  <?php
}
```

**Action for adding inline JavaScript**

```
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'theme_customize_js');
```

Comment: You can move this code in js file and use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/ function to pass PHP values to javascript.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems more like a hack than the correct way to achieve this (misuse of the localisation system). Think I'll keep to informing people to tweak their optimisation plugin settings unless there's a solution which looks right.

Comment: Not hack. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/10160612/1287548 https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96375/14347

Comment: Appreciate it's functionality that is built into Wordpress, however it is far more cumbersome to implement, requires using functions in a manner for which they are not designed and requires non-semanticly named functions. Thanks, but I'll think we'll have to agree to disagree here.

Comment: WordPress core uses the `wp_localize_script` function to do this on admin screens. It's the "official" means by which to do it.